# Result of multiplying both sides of not-big-O relationship by the same function?

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory

Is the following generally true?

`f∉O(g) ⇒ f*h∉O(g*h)`
Where f, h, g are positive-only functions. My intuition is that it is true, but I don't know how to prove it.

Here is why I think it is true:
Because f∉O(g) there is no c multiplied by g that will make f ≤ c*g for a large enough x. There is no valid c for g because either f and g alternate who is on top or f dominates g. For each x, the point f(x) and g(x) will be scaled by h(x), therefore if f(x) is above g(x), then h(x)f(x) will be above h(x)g(x). This would mean the lack of asymptotic dominance must remain the same when multiplied by h, right?

Comment: not true if for instance h is always a fraction i.e. 0 ≤ h ≤ 1. in that case g * h ≤ g which means that we may find a constant c for g * h

Answer (score 1):

Suppose f * h is O(g * h). Then there exist x0, c such that f(x) * h(x) <= c * g(x) * h(x) for all x >= x0. Since h is always positive, h(x) is positive and we are free to divide both sides of the inequality without changing sign. This yields f(x) <= c * g(x). Therefore, f * h in O(g * h) implies f in O(g).

What we have just shown to be true is the contrapositive of your claim. Your claim to prove is:

> if f is not O(g), then f * h is not O(g * h)

What we have just shown is:

> if f * h is O(g * h), then f is O(g)

Because all logical statements are logically equivalent to their contrapositives, your statement is also true. You can reason directly by multiplying one side of the inequality by the unity h(x)/h(x) and then multiplying through by h(x); but I thought canceling by division was clearer.

Comment: In the first paragraph, "This yields f(x) <= c * g(x) * h(x)." should read "This yields f(x) <= c * g(x)."